# In an SES of chain complexes in an abelian category two of complexes exact implies the third is exact.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

> Consider a short exact sequence of chain complexes: $$0_{\cdot} \rightarrow A_{\cdot} \xrightarrow{f} B_{\cdot} \xrightarrow{g} C_{\cdot} \rightarrow 0_{\cdot}$$
>   If any two of $A_{\cdot},B_{\cdot},C_{\cdot}$ are exact then so is the third.

I just want help proving it for one of the cases: starting with any two of the specific chain complexes being exact prove it for the third.

My attempt:  Let $B,C$ be exact  $\implies \ker d_n^i = \text{im } d_{n+1}^i$ for indexes $i= B,C$.  Now let $x \in \ker d^A_n$  Since $f$ is a morphism of chain complexes we have $d^B_n f_n = f_{n-1} d^A_n$.  So then $f_n(x) \in \ker d^B_n = \text{im } d^B_{n+1}$ and I'm lost.  Since $f$ is exact each $f_n$ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the long exact sequence for homology to obtain $$\cdots\longrightarrow  H_{n+1}(C_\cdot)\longrightarrow H_n(A_\cdot)\longrightarrow  H_n(B_\cdot) \longrightarrow H_n(C_\cdot) \longrightarrow  H_{n-1}(A_\cdot)\longrightarrow \cdots$$

and conclude. For example $C_\cdot,B_\cdot$ acyclic gives exact sequences $0\longrightarrow  H_n(A_\cdot) \longrightarrow 0$ so that $H_n(A_\cdot)=0$.

Comment: Could you explain the "long exact sequence for homology" ?

Comment: @EnjoysMath What do you mean by "explain"?

Comment: I haven't gotten that far in the book and I think the long exact sequence construction depends on the this question.

Comment: No, it really doesn't. The use of the LES for homology is the canonical solution to the question you pose.